# Where can I download RedisInsight v1.2.2 for Windows?

Tags: redis

I have RedisInsight v1.2.2 installed, and today I got prompted to upgrade to v1.3.0.

The problem is that the upgrade/install process tries to remove the older version (1.2.2) and needs the .msi I installed that version with, but I don't have that file anymore. And now I can't find anywhere to download it either.

Can anyone provide a link to download RedisInsight v1.2.2 (redisinsight-win-1.2.2.msi)

Comment: You can look under C:\Windows\Installer. Windows keeps the cache of the installed msi in that location. The problem is, you might see many directories with random names. You will have to search for .msi and then for each .msi right click -> details and then check whether it is coming from Redis. If you know the general date when you installed the 1.2.2 then you can narrow your search based on that date.

Comment: Thanks, I checked but it doesn't seem like Windows backed up that .msi. According to control panel I installed it on 12 Feb 2020, there's no .msi for that date. I checked every file two weeks in both directions, but none of them are for RedisInsight. I assume if Windows made a backup there it wouldn't be asking me where to find the file anyway right?

Comment: I suppose you are right. It was worth a try though. I think your best option is to contact support (if they have one) from RedisInsight and grab the old version. What about you manually uninstall the old version from control panel and then install the new one? Very risky if it removes the old data.

Comment: I tried that, but it won't do the uninstall without the .msi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got in contact with Redis support (as suggested by @Icarus3 - thanks)

They sent me a link to download version 1.2.2, I just had to rename the file to what it was before and then all was well.

I'm posting the link in case anyone else happens to have to same question and comes looking here for answers.

https://downloads.redisinsight.redislabs.com/1.2.2/redisinsight-win.msi

Comment: Im not sure whom to blame but the above link is flagged as a trojan virus, by windows defender and virus total  https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/1f2f628aee017094743a5635e4470bd4457eeeb798b3b145f4317193ab2b2687/detection

Comment: Please change the link to http://downloads.redisinsight.redislabs.com/latest/redisinsight-win.msi since in this old version Windows wrongly  marked the pyinstaller version as trojan and RedisInsight was using this pyinstaller version. Please upgrade to a newer version of RedisInsight.

Comment: For the version 2 the link is currently : https://download.redisinsight.redis.com/latest/RedisInsight-v2-win-installer.exe

But if you want to comply to the redis process, you should fill a form here: https://redis.com/redis-enterprise/redis-insight/#insight-form

Comment: # Updated - https://redis.com/thank-you/redisinsight-the-best-redis-gui-35/

Answer (score 6):

Here are the direct links for the latest versions if you don't want to fill in the form:

- Windows: https://download.redisinsight.redis.com/latest/RedisInsight-v2-win-installer.exe
- Mac (Intel): https://download.redisinsight.redis.com/latest/RedisInsight-v2-mac-x64.dmg
- Mac (M1): https://download.redisinsight.redis.com/latest/RedisInsight-v2-mac-arm64.dmg
- Linux (AppImage):  https://download.redisinsight.redis.com/latest/RedisInsight-v2-linux-x86_64.AppImage
- Linux (Debian): https://download.redisinsight.redis.com/latest/RedisInsight-v2-linux-amd64.deb